# For how many values of $n$ with $0\le n\le100$ is the graph of $f(x)=\sin(x+n)$ identical to the graph of $g(x)=\cos x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble with a precalculus problem.

For how many values of $n$ with $0\le n\le100$ is the graph of $f(x)=\sin(x+n)$ identical to the graph of $g(x)=\cos x$?

I know that the graphs are periodic, but I don't know how to use that information.

Comment: Must $n$ be an integer? Also, I fail to see at first glance how your title is related to the problem.

Comment: x doesn't have to be an integer

Answer (score 2):

We know $\sin(x+\pi/2) = \cos(x)$ . You can add as many $2\pi$ in the bracket of $\sin$ it would make no effect since $\sin(x) = \sin(x+2\pi)$ .

Therefore we can see that the series starts with $t = \pi/2$ . And for the last value of $n$ , put $\pi/2 + 2\pi t > 100 $ . We get $ t = 15 $ . Therefor the series $\pi/2+2\pi t$ for $t = 0,1,2\cdots15 $

Comment: You answered a second before me. So out of respect I have deleted my post!!